# ¿Es posible crear una función en MySQL que contenta un arreglo/vector?

Tags: mysql, funciones

Quisiera hacer una función en MySQL para realizar un calculo de un digito de verificación, para lo cual requiete tener un arreglo de 15 posiciones con unos valores constantes (no varian) y con ellos puedo hacer el resto del proceso.

¿Se puede hacer un arreglo en una función MySQL? he estado buscando información y no la he logrado conseguir.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias alternativas:

1) Puedes utilizar tablas temporales.

2) Puedes utilizar un JSON Array (si tu versión de mySQL es posterior a la 5.7).

```
SET @myjson = '["gmail.com","mail.ru","arcor.de","gmx.de","t-online.de",
            "web.de","googlemail.com","freenet.de","yahoo.de","gmx.net",
            "me.com","bluewin.ch","hotmail.com","hotmail.de","live.de",
            "icloud.com","hotmail.co.uk","yahoo.co.jp","yandex.ru"]';
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(@myjson);
-- result: 19
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@myjson, '$[0]');
-- result: gmail.com
```

3) Puedes simular con FIND_IN_SET()...

```
SET @c = 'xxx,yyy,zzz';
SELECT * from countries 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(countryname,@c);
```

El crédito va para https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta. Después se formular la inquietud, me puse a leer, alguien me dijo que podia utilizar la función: ELT(), y en mi función MySQL que lo requeria lo aplique y me funciono.

Ejemplo:

```
SET lnSuma := lnSuma + (lcValor * ELT(lnItem, 71, 67, 59, 53, 47, 43, 41, 37, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 7, 3));
```

Acá hago una multiplicación lnItem me da la posición que deseo y los valores son los números dentro de esta función, si lnItem = 1, el valor ees 71, y así.

De todas formas lo recomentado por @javier-reséndiz es aplicable